# creating roster from a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the original table that has raw data in such format:

```
gkey    Start_date  Finish_date Start_Hr Finish_hr  Name
 1      2014-01-01  2014-10-16  07       15         Smith  
 2      2014-01-01  2014-12-31  15       21         Johnes
 3      2014-01-01  2014-12-31  21       07         Adams
 4      2014-10-16  2014-12-31  21       07         Doe
 ...
```

And I'd like to display as a weekly roster in format

```
Shift      today      today+1     today+2      today+3....
Morning    Smith      Smith       Doe
Afternoon  Johnes     Johnes      Johnes
Evening   .....
```

I've started by putting it into nice virtual table

```
declare @d datetime
declare @c integer
declare @T table (
[day] datetime,
name varchar(max),
shift varchar(max)
)


 set @c=1
 set @d= getdate();


 while @c<=7
 begin
 insert into @T
 select @d as [day],
 name,
 case when finish_hr <=6 then 'Morning' when finish_hr<=15 then 'Afternoon' when     finish_hr<=23 then 'Evening' end as shift
from calling_roster where start_date <=@d and finish_date >@d


 set @c= @c+1
 set @d = dateadd(day,1,@d)
 end
```

So now I have it nicely set up as

```
day      name    shift
14-10    Smith   Morning
14-10    Johnes  Afternoon
14-10    Adams   Evening
15-10    Smith   Morning
```

And now I'm stuck...

Comment: Google "sql server pivot"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a PIVOT query.

Here, I've broken your dates out as days of the week:

```
SELECT [name], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday]
FROM (
    SELECT [name], DATENAME(dw, [day]) AS DayWeek, [shift]
    FROM table1
    ) AS src
    pivot (
        max([shift]) FOR DayWeek IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])
    ) AS pvt
```

You can see it working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d0a6/10)

Comment: Your next step might be to restrict the days to ones greater than today, then you'll see only those that affect your week.

Comment: If you want to make your days dynamic, you'll need to generate dynamic sql based on your current date and exec it.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I have to fiddle with pivot command, but I couldn't get the hang of it